# Program to connect Oracle Database using DataSource interface

Tags: java

I want to connect to Oracle database using DataSource interface not using DriverManager in java.
I don't have an idea about this. Please provide me a sample program to do so.

Comment: Please go through following link. It contains all the information needed to connect using data source information http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Comment: Follow the link this might help you !! [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to use a DataSource here is the way to go:

```
// Setup the datasource
DataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();// There is other DataSource offered by Oracle , check the javadoc for more information
ds.setDriverType("thin");
ds.setServerName("myServer");
ds.setPortNumber(1521);
ds.setDatabaseName("myDB");
ds.setUser("SCOTT");
ds.setPassword("TIGER");

// Get a JDBC connection
Connection c = ds.getConnection();
```

This what is roughtly done under the cover.

However, in real life project, you won't often do this. Let's say you build a web application. Usually, you'll configure a datasource in text format and drop this configuration on your container. Later, you can retreive the datasource  through JNDI (see @Radhamani Muthusamy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20993785/363573)).

Answer (score 2):

First create a `Datasource` file. The datasource filename can be given in `properties file`.Use the following code

```
ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle
            .getBundle("com.cactus.xorail.properties.ConnectionProperties");
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/"
                    + rb.getString("Datasource"));
            if (ds == null) {
                throw new SQLException(
                        "Please configure datasource with name DS");
            }
```

```
        result = ds.getConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

// Setting up the DataSource object

```
  oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource ds 
    = new oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource();
  ds.setDriverType("thin");
  ds.setServerName("localhost");
  ds.setPortNumber(1521);
  ds.setDatabaseName("XE"); // Oracle SID
  ds.setUser("Herong");
  ds.setPassword("TopSecret");
```

// Getting a connection object

`con = ds.getConnection();`